# No module named main while importing wkhtmltopdf

Tags: python-3.x, wkhtmltopdf

I have installed wkhtmltopdf wrapper from pypy using pip command. And the module is installed correctly but when I try to import the module I get the error as follows:

```
ImportError: No module named 'main'
```

Please provide me the solution. I am using Python 3.5.2

I am parsing the page http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/amazon-interview-experience-set-324-sde2/ and extracting the interview text from this page in the form of html using beautifulsoup. And then I want to convert the html to pdf file. I am trying to use wkhtmltopdf for that.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your usecase?

Comment: Also, how are you importing?

Comment: I am using the import command to import the module. I edited the question to tell you the usecase.

Comment: the same problem here! it seems that it does not work for python3.5  :(